# MIDI file processing in Matlab

Tags: matlab, mp3, midi

I have an MP3 file. I found the amplitude and frequency values for it. I need to evaluate.
So I decided to check with MIDI file of the MP3. How to get the amplitude and frequency value on per frame basis from the MIDI file?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can do it using [MIDI toolbox](https://www.jyu.fi/hum/laitokset/musiikki/en/research/coe/materials/miditoolbox), for example.
Otherwise you have to implement MIDI file parser yourself as MatLab does not have its own one.